# Ionic 3 block backbutton Event

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I would like to intercept the back button event.
As soon as the listener is called, the back signal is already triggered.

This is what i tried:

```
 document.addEventListener("backbutton", () => {
       console.log("[WARN] BackBtn pushed");
       console.log("TextboxVal: " + this.inputValue);
       this.showConfirm();
       document.removeEventListener("backbutton");
     });
```

I dont want to lose the "this.inputValue" value.
But in the most cases its gone already.

Comment: You might want to think about cookies https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies-js and Reactive Forms. https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms That way if you move away and return state can be preserved. Vasco on the Angular University did something on this in his RxJS tutorial videos. See https://angular-university.io/lesson/angular-rxjs-reactive-patterns-reactive-forms-draft-data-saving-implementation In effect it uses form.valueChanges, and sets a cookie whenever the form is in a valid state with a filter

Comment: There are several ways to fix that, but I'm not sure of what are the requirements on your end. You could a) Store the value in the storage, so when the user returns to the page, the value will be there b) Show an alert before leaving the page, and if the user still wants to leave, clear that input and go back to the previous page. If any of this may work, let me know and I'll add an answer with more details.

Comment: I want to show an alert before leaving the page.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to show an alert before leaving the page.

You can use [`NavGuards`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#nav-guards) for that:

> In some cases, a developer should be able to control views leaving and
>   entering. To allow for this, `NavController` has the `ionViewCanEnter`
>   and `ionViewCanLeave` methods. Similar to Angular route guards, but
>   are more integrated with `NavController`.

```
  // ...

  ionViewCanLeave() {

    if(this.inputValue) {
      // Show the alert
      this.presentConfirm();
    }

    // Will leave if the input is null
    return this.inputValue === null;
  }

  presentConfirm() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Exit',
      message: 'Do you want to exit?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel'
        },
        {
          text: 'Exit',
          handler: () => {

            // Allow the user to exit this page
            this.inputValue = null;

            // Go back to the previous page
            setTimeout(() => { this.navCtrl.pop(); }, 500);

          }
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats how i done it by myself:

```
constructor(public plt: Platform) {
    //Catch BackBTN Event
        plt.ready().then( ()=> {
          plt.registerBackButtonAction( ()=> {
            this.showConfirm();
          })
        });​
}

showConfirm() {
      let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: this.confirm,
        message: this.confirm_msg,
        buttons: [
          {
            text: this.disagree,
            handler: () => {
              console.log("Saved changes");
              this.dismiss();
            }
          },
          {
            text: this.agree,
            handler: () => {
              console.log("Discard changes");
              this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
            }
          }
        ]
      });
      confirm.present();
    }
  }
```

With this i can set my own custom BackBTN method.

Comment: The problem with that approach is that that behaviour will be set for all the pages, and not only in that page. You could try to un-register the custom back button handler, but sometimes it leads to some bugs in the app when several pages are pushed/popped from the stack.